# ListView setOnItemClickListener get the wrong item when adpater.notifyDataSetChanged was called

Tags: android, listview

I am using a listview to show the progress of a download list.
I use a thread to update the progress every second by calling notifyDataSetChanged in a handler.
It all works fine until i try to use setOnItemClickListener to get the item clicked in the list.when the update thread is running,the result of onItemClick is unpredictable,i clicked the first item in the list but the result of onItemClick shown i clicked the second one.
I assume it is because the data is changed when the item was clicked but how can i prevent it?
i tried to set a isListItemBeenClicked flag to true when item is clicked,and the update thread  only call notifyDataSetChanged when isListItemBeenClicked is false,but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me on this?

PS:sorry for my lame english

Code:

1.Refresh handler

```
    listViewRefreshHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            if(!isListItemBeenClicked){
                System.out.println("start refresh");
                downloadingTaskList.clear();
                uploadingTaskList.clear();
                completedTaskList.clear();
                downloadingTaskList.addAll(transferService.getDownloadingTaskList());
                uploadingTaskList.addAll(transferService.getUploadingTaskList());
                completedTaskList.addAll(transferService.getCompletedTaskList());
                Collections.sort(completedTaskList, new Comparator<TransferTask>(){
                    @Override
                    public int compare(TransferTask transferTask1, TransferTask transferTask2) {
                        int ret=0;
                        long result=transferTask2.getCompletedDate().getTime()-transferTask1.getCompletedDate().getTime();
                        if(result==0){
                            ret=0;
                        }else if(result>0){
                            ret=1;
                        }else{
                            ret=-1;
                        }
                        return ret;
                    }

                });
                downloadingTaskListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                completedTaskListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                uploadingTaskListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println("refresh end");
            }
        }
    };
```

2.OnItemClickListener

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            isListItemBeenClicked=true;
            System.out.println("click start");
            TransferTask downloadTask=(TransferTask)view.getTag();
            System.out.println("click "+downloadTask.getFileName());
            System.out.println("click end");
            isListItemBeenClicked=false;

        }
    });
```

3.Update Thread

```
        new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (!isStop) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    listViewRefreshHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

4.TransferTaskListAdapter

```
public class TransferTaskListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {   

    private Context context;   
    private List<TransferTask> transeferTaskList;

    public TransferTaskListAdapter(Context context, List<TransferTask> downloadTaskList ) {    
        this.context = context;   
        this.transeferTaskList = downloadTaskList;   
    }   

    public int getCount() {                           
        return transeferTaskList.size();   
    }   

    public TransferTask getItem(int position) {        
        return transeferTaskList.get(position);   
    }   

    public long getItemId(int position) {     
        return position;   
    }   
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("get view called");
        TransferTask transferTask=getItem(position);
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.transfering_task, null);
        }
        convertView.setTag(transferTask);
        ImageView taskStatusImageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskStatus);
        TransferTaskStatus tastStatus=transferTask.getStatus();
        switch(tastStatus){
            case DOWNLOADING:
                taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_download);
                break;
            case UPLOADING:
                taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_upload);
                break;
            case PAUSED :
                taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_paused);
                break;
            case COMPLETED:
                if(transferTask.getType().equals(TaskType.DONWLOAD)){
                    taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_download);
                }else{
                    taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_upload);
                }

                break;
            case WAITING:
                taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_waiting);
                break;
            case STARTING:
                taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_waiting);
                break;
            case STOPPING:
                taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_waiting);
                break;
            default:
                taskStatusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_failed);
        }

        String fileName=transferTask.getFileName();
        TextView fileNameTextView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fileName);
        fileNameTextView.setText(fileName);

        long size=transferTask.getSize();
        long transferedSize=transferTask.getTransferedSize();
        FileTransferProgressBar progressBar=(FileTransferProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgress);
        progressBar.setTotalFileSize(size);
        progressBar.setTransferedFileSize(transferedSize);
        System.out.println("get view end");
        return convertView;   
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

`TransferTask downloadTask = (TransferTask)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

rather than your current:

`TransferTask downloadTask=(TransferTask)view.getTag();`

Comment: i will try,but what is the different?

Comment: I think both methods should work to be honest but just give it a shot and see if it helps. I am only suggesting it as I've never used the View parameter before myself and have never had any problems.

Comment: At a guess I'd say it might be to do with how views get recycled within the ListView when they scroll off screen. Regardless, the docs say to use getItemAtPosition(position) to fetch any data associated with the ListView.